# JQuery .data() not fetching values after I change them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data attribute called registeredteacherid. For some reason the values aren't getting fetched correctly after I update them. Here is a general idea of what I'm doing.

```
var registeredTeacherId = $(eventPanel).data('registeredteacherid');
// do some work...then
$(eventPanel).data('registeredteacherid', response.teacherId);
// at this point it sets the new value in the IE debugger window
// do some more work
// then I fetch the value again and it still shows the old value
var registeredTeacherId = $(eventPanel).data('registeredteacherid');
```

Comment: create this as a snippet or fiddle.  This will not reproduce your problem as far as I can tell.  Please ensure that any posted code reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` function will not change the value of your `data-*` attribute, but it will give you access to these values.

You can always change the values and get the new data, and if you want to change the content of the `data-*` attribute you can use the `attr` function:

```js
console.log($('div').data('content'));
console.log($('div').attr('data-content'));
$('div').data('content', 'some new content');
console.log($('div').data('content'));
console.log($('div').attr('data-content'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-content="this is the content">Text</div>
```

Comment: .data can't change it?

Comment: `.data` will change the attached data, but not the the value of the attribute.

Comment: It looks like you can change it in the documnetaion

Comment: what's the diff between attached data and attribute value?

Comment: The attached data as the associated data with that element. It can be object/reference/array/anything javascript supports. It is not part of the DOM. When you talk about attributes - the values are strings.

Comment: so if I'm creating and setting a data-attribute in the view, how would I correctly change it in jquery? Would I use .attr('data-attribute', value) or .data('attribute', value)

Comment: If you need to work with the data - use the `data` function. If for some reason you need the attribute - use the `attr`.

Comment: I'm still confused. I just want to create a data-attribute in an element and give it a value ex. data-teacherid=123. I want to be able to change this value in jquery/javascript.

Comment: so use `data`. If you have some other script that reads that attribute - you must use `attr`.

Comment: well I'm reading that attribute in other parts of the script, but not a different script

Comment: If your entire script will use `data` - you are ok. If part of use uses `data` and part uses `attr` - you have problems. You should use only `data` and everything will work.

Comment: what!? So your saying that if I have .attr('data-attribute', value) somewhere else in my script. Say 10 lines below .data() then I'll have some problem? If yes, what is that problem?

Comment: The problem is that `data` **will not** change that attribute. Did you check my answer? It's there with a complete example...

Comment: but your code shows that when you change the data with .data() then fetch the data with data it fetches the changed value

Comment: ok I just tested outputting data vs attr and I see data() won't update the DOM. So if my objective is to store a variable in the DOM as a data-attribute then I should be manipulating that value with attr() right???

Comment: I already wrote it several times - if you need to change attributes - use `attr`.

Comment: so is .data() just come type of internal variable?